Правка или изменение интернет ссылок
Установил цифровые часы. При наведении и клик ПКМ есть активная строчка интернет-ссылки. Хотел бы изменить их. Посмотреть где они в открытом коде и попробовать:https://freesoft.ru/windows/clock-plus-7091/versions/21-169717. Как открыть код, не знаю.
